# How to sum of certain values using pandas datetime operations

Tags: pandas

Headline is not clear. Let me explain.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Order Quantity            Date Accepted        Date Delivered
     20                     01-05-2010            01-02-2011
     10                     01-11-2010            01-03-2011
     300                    01-12-2010            01-04-2011
     5                      01-03-2011            01-03-2012
     20                     01-04-2012            01-11-2013
     10                     01-07-2013            01-12-2014
```

I want to basically create another column that contains the total undelivered items for each row.

Expected output:

```
Order Quantity            Date Accepted        Date Delivered      Pending Order
     20                     01-05-2010            01-02-2011             20
     10                     01-11-2010            01-03-2011             30
     300                    01-12-2010            01-04-2011             330
     5                      01-03-2011            01-03-2012             305
     20                     01-04-2012            01-11-2013             20
     10                     01-07-2013            01-12-2014             30
```

Comment: Explain the logic of the calculation please.

Comment: Each row's date is equal to "Date Accepted". So, If the item is not delivered before this date, then we increase Pending order value. If it is delivered, we decrease it.

Comment: @Erfan is it clear now?

Comment: how can you have that 20 and 30 in the last two rows in the pending order, when the date deliver is not before the date accepted?

Comment: In 5th row or on `01-04-2012`, only 20 items are not delivered. The delivery date of all the previous orders is before. Then on 01-07-2013, 10 more orders are added, and those 20 + 10 are not delivered

Answer (score 2):

Here, I have taken a part of your dataframe and try to get the result.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'order': [20, 10, 300, 200], 
                   'Date_aceepted': ['01-05-2010', '01-11-2010', '01-12-2010', '01-12-2010'],
                   'Date_delever': ['01-02-2011', '01-03-2011', '01-04-2011', '01-12-2010']})

  order Date_aceepted Date_delever
0     20    01-05-2010   01-02-2011
1     10    01-11-2010   01-03-2011
2    300    01-12-2010   01-04-2011
3    200    01-12-2010   01-12-2010
```

Then I will change the Date_accepted and Date_deliver to date time by using pandas data time module

```
df['date1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_aceepted'])

df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_delever'])
```

Then I will make a new data frame in which the Date_accepted and Date_delever are not the same. I assume you just need that in your final result.

```
dff = df[df['date1'] != df['date2']]
```

You can see the last row in which both accepted and delever are same is now removed in dff.

```
   order Date_aceepted Date_delever      date1      date2
0     20    01-05-2010   01-02-2011 2010-01-05 2011-01-02
1     10    01-11-2010   01-03-2011 2010-01-11 2011-01-03
2    300    01-12-2010   01-04-2011 2010-01-12 2011-01-04
```

Then I did use pandas cumsum of pending order

```
dff['pending'] = dff['order'].cumsum()
```

and it gives

```
  order Date_aceepted Date_delever      date1      date2  pending
0     20    01-05-2010   01-02-2011 2010-01-05 2011-01-02       20
1     10    01-11-2010   01-03-2011 2010-01-11 2011-01-03       30
2    300    01-12-2010   01-04-2011 2010-01-12 2011-01-04      330
```

The final data frame has two extra columns that can be dropped if you don't want in your result.

Comment: But it does not subtract the delivered items. That is the main thing. Thanks a lot for the effort.