# How to convert this forloop to pandas lambda function, to increase speed

Tags: python, pandas

This forloop will take 3 days to complete. How can I increase the speed?

```
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    df.loc[df['Creation date'] >= pd.to_datetime(str(df['Original conf GI dte'].iloc[i])),'delivered'] += df['Sale order item'].iloc[i]
```

I think the forloop is enough to understand?

If Creation date is bigger than Original conf GI date, then add `Sale order item` value to `delivered` column.

Each row's date is "Date Accepted"  (`Date Delivered` is future date).  Input is `Order Ouantity`, `Date Accepted` & `Date Delivered`....Output is `Delivered` column

```
Order Quantity            Date Accepted        Date Delivered       Delivered
     20                     01-05-2010            01-02-2011           0
     10                     01-11-2010            01-03-2011           0
     300                    01-12-2010            01-09-2011           0     
     5                      01-03-2011            01-03-2012           30
     20                     01-04-2012            01-11-2013           335
     10                     01-07-2013            01-12-2014           335
```

Comment: Please post a small sample of the input and the corresponding desired output.

Answer (score 3):

Convert values to numpy arrays by [`Series.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html), compare them with broadcasting, match `order` values by [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and last `sum`:

```
date1 = df['Date Accepted'].to_numpy()
date2 = df['Date Delivered'].to_numpy()
order = df['Order Quantity'].to_numpy()

#oldier pandas versions
#date1 = df['Date Accepted'].values
#date2 = df['Date Delivered'].values
#order = df['Order Quantity'].values

df['Delivered1'] = np.where(date1[:, None] >= date2, order, 0).sum(axis=1)
print (df)
   Order Quantity Date Accepted Date Delivered  Delivered  Delivered1
0              20    2010-01-05     2011-01-02          0           0
1              10    2010-01-11     2011-01-03          0           0
2             300    2010-01-12     2011-01-09          0           0
3               5    2011-01-03     2012-01-03         30          30
4              20    2012-01-04     2013-01-11        335         335
5              10    2013-01-07     2014-01-12        335         335
```

Comment: It is not giving the same results. I will try to explain more, thank you

Comment: It is related to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438685/how-to-sum-of-certain-values-using-pandas-datetime-operations?noredirect=1#comment105062434_59438685

Comment: I found a way to calculate `TotalOrdersCreated` (using cumsum), now I am trying to find a way to calculate `Delivered`. Then I will subtract TotalOrdersCreated-Delivered, to generate `Pending`. (Pending is the expected output in that question). Is it clear now sir?

Comment: @TomHolland - I think yes, in your solution is not necessary sum something like `df['Creation date'] >= pd.to_datetime(str(df['Original conf GI dte'].iloc[i])).sum()` ?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get how  to implement the above line in the code

Comment: @TomHolland - Is possible add some sample data and expected output?

Comment: Add some sample input & output

Comment: Hey. My Dataframe has millions of rows, and I do not have enough memory  (32 gb only) in my laptop to run the above code. Any memory optimized way?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use  [`np.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for speed. Currently you are looping on the dataframe rows whereas numpy operations are designed to operate on the entire column:

```
cond= df['Creation date'].ge(pd.to_datetime(str(df['Original conf GI dte'])))
df['delivered']=np.where(cond,df['delivered']+df['Sale order item'],df['delivered'])
```